# Are all Disgaea 2: Dark Hero Days DLC Characters level 1 unlocks

Tags: disgaea-2

I was reading on the Wiki that with Pram in Dark Hero Days you have to fight her while with Pleinair you don't have to fight her

i am wondering if all the DLC characters are unlocked at the very beginning (meaning you can recruit them) and/or if you have to fight them before they are recruited into your party at that level

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Had just enough credit after getting Hyperdimension Neptunia V DLC to get Disgaea Dark Hero Days DLC, after starting the game there is a separate Location which is Hanako's summoning experiments, however all of them are Level 100. Pleinair is also Level 100 yet you don't have to fight her so you can use her to beat the others.

if your like me and wanted to get the DLC character to fill up your party in a brand new game on the first cycle (really i just wanted Pleinair and Pram) then you can unlock Pleinair, have her beat one of the DLC characters an then each character you unlock have them beat the next one, with the last just get Friday Mk 2 to show up in the village and beat her with the final character, with them all having 100 Mana it's simply going to the first map and grinding a little mana to reincarnate them all to level 1, bonus to this also is that you'll get almost 70,000 Hel which you can use to buy equipment without worry